# Is there a way to find out that the All Apps screen is shown?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm creating a live wallpaper for Android and ran into an issue with the manual scrolling (without using the onOffsetsChanged method). The scrolling works like a charm except for one, but very unpleasent side-effect - when a user opens the "AllApps" screen and this screen is semi-transparent (like on the Xperia phones), the wallpaper keeps on reacting the touch events when the user goes through screens with his/her installed apps and scrolls.

I understand that nothing is changed from the wallpaper's "point of view" if this screen is semi-transparent. It keeps on rendering and continues to process all the touch events.

So, the question is - is there a way to track down the moment when a user opens the "AllApps" screen and stop processing touch events until this screen is closed? Any ideas?

Comment: I want to say that this is the expected behavior of live wallpapers. I just did the same thing with one of my favorite live wallpapers and it reacted to touch as well, even though I was technically touching a different view. Is there any reason that the touch event shouldn't go off?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a sort of synchronization between the current screen and the wallpaper position. In short, I'm trying to emulate the onOffsetsChanged method behavior and I can say that mostly I succeeded. However, when the wallpaper is scrolled from the AllApps screen (or maybe another transparent view), the home screen position isn't changed, so the wallpaper and the screen position synchronization gets broken. It's no big deal actually, but some users complain about this.